# Can't extract geo keys - Working with Atlas but not Local MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodes, mongoose-schema, mongodb-geospatial

Please refer to this issue [Here](https://github.com/Mockgoose/Mockgoose/issues/21)

I have same issue except i am not providing any geo data.

My Model's geo data implementation portion below

```
     startLocation: {
      // GeoJSON
      type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Point',
        enum: ['Point']
      },
      coordinates: [Number],
      address: String,
      description: String
    },
    locations: [
      {
        type: {
          type: String,
          default: 'Point',
          enum: ['Point']
        },
        coordinates: [Number],
        address: String,
        description: String,
        day: Number
      }
    ]
```

Same Request Body for each case below

```
{
    "name": "The Test Tourxx",
    "duration": 1,
    "maxGroupSize": 1,
    "difficulty": "medium",
    "price": 501,
    "summary": "Nothing exciting here man!",
    "imageCover": "tour-3-cover.jpg",
    "ratingsAverage": 4,
    "guides": ["5e85e24bd1b3f918dc07bb3d", "5e85e262d1b3f918dc07bb3e"]
}
```

Response when connected local MongoDB below

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "error": {
        "driver": true,
        "name": "MongoError",
        "index": 0,
        "code": 16755,
        "errmsg": "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5e85fc64a4031f1734b55515'), startLocation: { type: \"Point\", coordinates: [] }, ratingsAverage: 4, ratingsQuantity: 0, rating: 4.5, images: [], createdAt: new Date(1585839200315), startDates: [], secretTour: false, guides: [ ObjectId('5e85e24bd1b3f918dc07bb3d'), ObjectId('5e85e262d1b3f918dc07bb3e') ], name: \"The Test Tourxx\", duration: 1, maxGroupSize: 1, difficulty: \"medium\", price: 501, summary: \"Nothing exciting here man!\", imageCover: \"tour-3-cover.jpg\", locations: [], slug: \"the-test-tourxx\", __v: 0 }  Point must only contain numeric elements",
        "statusCode": 500,
        "status": "error"
    },
    "stack": "MongoError: Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5e85fc64a4031f1734b55515'), startLocation: { type: \"Point\", coordinates: [] }, ratingsAverage: 4, ratingsQuantity: 0, rating: 4.5, images: [], createdAt: new Date(1585839200315), startDates: [], secretTour: false, guides: [ ObjectId('5e85e24bd1b3f918dc07bb3d'), ObjectId('5e85e262d1b3f918dc07bb3e') ], name: \"The Test Tourxx\", duration: 1, maxGroupSize: 1, difficulty: \"medium\", price: 501, summary: \"Nothing exciting here man!\", imageCover: \"tour-3-cover.jpg\", locations: [], slug: \"the-test-tourxx\", __v: 0 }  Point must only contain numeric elements\n    at Function.create (C:\\Users\\Cody\\Desktop\\X-Files\\NodeJS\\4-natours\\node_modules\\mongodb\\lib\\core\\error.js:43:12)\n    at toError (C:\\Users\\Cody\\Desktop\\X-Files\\NodeJS\\4-natours\\node_modules\\mongodb\\lib\\utils.js:149:22)\n    at C:\\Users\\Cody\\Desktop\\X-Files\\NodeJS\\4-natours\\node_modules\\mongodb\\lib\\operations\\common_functions.js:265:39\n    at handler (C:\\Users\\Cody\\Desktop\\X-Files\\NodeJS\\4-natours\\node_modules\\mongodb\\lib\\core\\sdam\\topology.js:913:24)\n    at C:\\Users\\Cody\\Desktop\\X-Files\\NodeJS\\4-natours\\node_modules\\mongodb\\lib\\cmap\\connection_pool.js:352:13\n    at handleOperationResult (C:\\Users\\Cody\\Desktop\\X-Files\\NodeJS\\4-natours\\node_modules\\mongodb\\lib\\core\\sdam\\server.js:487:5)\n    at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\\Users\\Cody\\Desktop\\X-Files\\NodeJS\\4-natours\\node_modules\\mongodb\\lib\\cmap\\connection.js:270:5)\n    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:311:20)\n    at processIncomingData (C:\\Users\\Cody\\Desktop\\X-Files\\NodeJS\\4-natours\\node_modules\\mongodb\\lib\\cmap\\message_stream.js:144:12)\n    at MessageStream._write (C:\\Users\\Cody\\Desktop\\X-Files\\NodeJS\\4-natours\\node_modules\\mongodb\\lib\\cmap\\message_stream.js:42:5)\n    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:441:12)\n    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:425:5)\n    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:316:11)\n    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:714:22)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)\n    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)"
}
```

Response when connected to MongoDB Atlas(Removed unrelated potion) below

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "tour": {
            "startLocation": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": []
            },
            "ratingsAverage": 4,
            "images": [],
            "guides": [
                "5e85e24bd1b3f918dc07bb3d",
                "5e85e262d1b3f918dc07bb3e"
            ],
            "_id": "5e85fb952754013728fc950c",
            "name": "The Test Tourxx",
            "duration": 1,
            "maxGroupSize": 1,
            "difficulty": "medium",
            "price": 501,
            "summary": "Nothing exciting here man!",
            "imageCover": "tour-3-cover.jpg",
            "locations": [],
            "__v": 0,
        }
    }
}
```

As it can be seen local db throws error when creating empty array for "locations"  but Atlas does it just fine.Please Help me identify the cause.

Mongoose: 5.9.7
Mockgoose: Not Used in the project
MongoDB: 4.2.3(Local and Atlas both)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a production code and you're working with small amounts of data, so drop your tours collection in compass and then run the script to import the data again. I have no idea why it works, but it works. I'm guessing it's some problem with old indexes? I don't know, It worked for me.

So if this doesn't work for you I guess you're just getting this error because you have startLocation as an 2dsphere index and maybe mongo is requiring you to input data there.

Try to create the tour below

```
    {
    "name": "The test tttttttt",
    "duration": 4,
    "maxGroupSize": 10,
    "difficulty": "easy",
    "price": 1,
    "summary": "Exciting testt",
    "imageCover": "mimimi.png",
    "startLocation": {
    "description": "Aspen, USA",
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-106.822318, 39.190872],
    "address": "419 S Mill St, Aspen, CO 81611, USA"
    }
}
```

All I did was add the startLocation object.